# Android: Keep service running, stop when app closed (removed from app tray)

Tags: android, service

I have a location service which I want to run at all times when the app is in the foreground, or in the background, but to stop when the app is closed (removed from the app tray)

My solution has been to start the service using `START_NOT_STICKY` and this seems to work, but I'm concerned by what the service documentation says about this command

> START_NOT_STICKY says that, after returning from onStartCreated(), if the process is killed with no remaining start commands to deliver, then the service will be stopped instead of restarted. This makes a lot more sense for services that are intended to only run while executing commands sent to them. For example, a service may be started every 15 minutes from an alarm to poll some network state. If it gets killed while doing that work, it would be best to just let it be stopped and get started the next time the alarm fires.

So it seems that Android may kill off services when memory is low, and if using `START_NOT_STICKY` the service will not be restarted.

I tried using `START_STICKY` but this keeps the service running even after the app is closed.

What can I do to keep the service running at all times while the app is in the foreground or background, and stop after being closed, but without worrying about Android terminating it while the app is running?

Code here if it matters:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){

    if (intent != null) {
        extras = intent.getExtras();

        // takes the messenger object and makes it local so when the messagereceiver sends an intent here, it won't overwrite the extras object
        // and get rid of the messenger. Otherwise, getting an update from the notification controls would null out the messenger object
        if (intent.hasExtra("MESSENGER")) {
            Timber.e("MESSENGER ");
            messenger = (Messenger) extras.get("MESSENGER");
        }
    }
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do to keep the service running at all times while the app is in the foreground or background, and stop after being closed, but without worrying about Android terminating it while the app is running?

I'm not sure what "app tray" you're referring to or what exactly you mean by "closed" (Android apps are not things that are "closed", per se.

But, from your description, I'd think you want to do something like:

- Start your Service when the user starts your app and bind to while the activity is in the foreground
- If your activity is paused (or stopped), unbind from the service and start a foreground notification to keep the service alive and the user aware that it's still running
- Instead of trying to detect when the app is "closed", which you can't really do, attach a "cancel" action to the foreground notification so the user can cancel it whenever they want

If that doesn't solve your issue, please elaborate on your use case and why you want to do this. I or others may be able to provide more / better / alternate suggestions with more specifics about what you're actually ultimately trying to achieve.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Closed meaning on a phone, explicitly showing all running apps and swiping to 'kill' it. Is there a way to ensure the service continues to run without a foreground notification? As it is now, my service does continue to run while the app is in the background, so the notification doesn't seem totally necessary.

Comment: As you saw, returning START_STICKY will restart your service if it wasn't explicitly stopped. As for your service continuing to run, Oreo introduced limits: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#back-all
So while it might appear to work now, it's not guaranteed.